# Split DVD iso of TV series into episodes

Tags: video, dvd, handbrake

I have a lot of DVD isos (I also have the physical DVD's, but I have ripped them, so they shouldn't be needed for this), of various TV series. Each DVD contains several episodes of the series, but typically several audio tracks and sets of subtitles.

Now I'd like to make a series of files, each one containing just one episode, and just one audio track and (in most cases) no subtitles. As space is not really an issue, but quality matters to me, I would prefer if it can be done with no new encoding (it is theoretically impossible that it improves quality, that would require magic), and it takes time/CPU cycles that is not needed. As long as my XMBC/OpenElec/Kodi (I don't care about those things, so I don't know what is the relevant component to name here, those are the names I was able to quickly find in it's "setup" menu) can play the result I don't really care about the format(s) involved.

I've found out that HandBrake can do something, but many of it's options are greek to me, and what I've managed to get it to do seems to involve re-encoding.

Any advice on how I can accomplish what I want? (I want to run this on a Debian box)